# Microprocessor instructions per cycle clock

Tags: microprocessor

Could you please explain this issue: can a microprocessor perform on average more than one instruction per clock cycle?

Comment: If you are asking 'is there any UP that can do that under any specific circumstances'? Yes, definitely. It is called multi-issue (within one CPU). If you are asking whether all UP's can do that under all circumstances: definitely No.

Comment: This question is too vague: what do you mean by "perform an instruction"? Modern out of order superscalar cpus do black magic with the pipeline, the registers and the datapath, and depending on what you mean that can be both true or false. A more human-comprehensible cpu can perform 1 instruction per clock cycle (or less), period.

Comment: This *might* be a duplicate of ["How can a CPU deliver more than one instruction per cycle?"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/123760/15426)